# Set and remove readonly property in ext Js

Tags: extjs, readonly

In extJs I need to disable one field until edit button is clicked.

```
xtype:'textfield',
fieldLabel: 'Address',
name:'streetAddress',
labelWidth: 48,                         
maxLength: 100,                         
cls: 'appAddresscls',
id: 'resume-applicantdetails-view-address',
allowBlank : false,
//readOnly:true,
skipValue:true
```

When loading I called

```
Ext.getCmp('resume-applicantdetails-view-address').getEl().dom.setAttribute('readOnly', true);
```

When editing

```
Ext.getCmp('resume-applicantdetails-view-address').getEl().dom.removeAttribute('readOnly');
```

But the field is always in edit mode. Actually I try this because, the disabled fields in IE appears in gray color.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
xtype:'textfield',
fieldLabel: 'Address',
name:'streetAddress',
labelWidth: 48,                         
maxLength: 100,                         
cls: 'appAddresscls',
id: 'resume-applicantdetails-view-address',
allowBlank : false,
readOnly:false,
skipValue:true
```

When loading I called

```
Ext.getCmp('resume-applicantdetails-view-address').setReadOnly(true);
```

When editing

```
Ext.getCmp('resume-applicantdetails-view-address').setReadOnly(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep disabled:true and add the following css in your page to make such fields appear normal as others:

```
.x-item-disabled .x-form-item-label,
.x-item-disabled .x-form-cb-label {
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90);
     opacity: 0.9; 
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the field to be disabled: true in config then in the edit button call function to renable.

```
Ext.getCmp('resume-applicantdetails-view-address').setDisabled(false);
```

Comment: When disabling, it will turn back to gray color.

Comment: Are you saying you do not wish the fields to be greyed out? If not then apply a style using the fieldClass: config option to change this

Answer (score 0):

**To set disable:**

```
Ext.get('resume-applicantdetails-view-address').set({disabled:'disabled'});
```

**To remove disable:**

```
Ext.get('resume-applicantdetails-view-address').set({disabled:''});
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to change the readOnly property on run time:

```
component.el.dom.readOnly = true;
```